# send webhook to ArgoWorkflow without exposing webhook

Tags: github, kubernetes, argocd, gitops, argo

I am pretty confused while asking this question.

I have a kubernetes cluster residing on-perm. and most of the services are on github( connected to dockerhub). Now I am trying to implement gitops using Argo.

I want to receive github webhook events on argo-workflow but I cannot use the public IP. nor can expose any service.

all my services are pull-based. Is there any way I could do pull-based events to github? and trigger my argo.

Comment: can you write a github poller, then publish a custom event which argo-workflows can consume? Its a significant am of work, but its a way.

Comment: Is there any github poller available? I tried a lot but could not find one.